# transform:scale vs traditional resizing

Tags: image, css, transform, scaling

Are there any drawbacks of using `transform: scale(x.x)` instead of doing traditional resizing with the width and height properties? Does scaling produce a lower quality image or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scale` generates a general better quality result (from a visual point of view) because many browsers render it via GPU (in other words, with hardware acceleration) using advanced resampling algotithms, but it has a drawback:

*Scaled object does not create a space around it, larger than its original size*.

Practically.... Browsers' behaviour is the following (approximately):

1. Render of the object "A" in its original size
2. Placing of other objects around it (until this point browsers completely ignore `scale` rule declaration)
3. At the end, "*visually*" scaling of "A", overlapping others like it would be in a different layer

Answer (score 3):

`transform:scale();` will not expand or shrink initial space used by your element.

a 100px square may look 200px , but will still use 100px² on screen . it will overlap what's around.