# CSS3: Lines of text sliding into page at different times

Tags: javascript, css

I have the code shown below that slides text into the page from right to left using css3 animation.
 I am using a different animation-delay for each line, but I have the problem that before the animation starts the lines are already visible on the left, and I don't want that.
Are there any means
a) to keep the text lines invisible before animation starts or
b) a simple way to load the lines at different times (maybe using javascript setTimeout?) or other tricks?
(note: I am using Firefox 35.0.1)

Help would be much appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

h1 {
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0%   { margin-left: 100%; }
  100% { margin-left: 0%;   }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="animation-delay: 0s;">ONE</h1>
<h1 style="animation-delay: 1s;">TWO</h1>
<h1 style="animation-delay: 3s;">THREE</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `opacity: 0;` to the initial element and `opacity: 1;` to the animation.
However, you need to retain the opacity after the animation ends. So the `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` comes to help.

Update: using `transform: translate(100%);` thanks to @Luca Detomi

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<head>
<style>

h1 {
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  opacity: 0;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0%   { transform: translate(101%); opacity:1; }
  100% { transform: translate(0%); opacity:1;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="animation-delay: 0s;">ONE</h1>
<h1 style="animation-delay: 1s;">TWO</h1>
<h1 style="animation-delay: 3s;">THREE</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, I'm using Chrome and, thereby, the awesome prefixfree library here. (Assuming other users' browser preference isn't a good practice for F2E developers, indeed)

Comment: I tried initial opacity: 0; and end opacity: 1; before and it didn't work because text was clear after the amimation. But using animation-fill-mode: forwards; it works, that was the secret! Thank you!

Comment: And Thank you for the hint with the prefix-library for Google Chrome, I didn't see it first but it is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

You may simply set an higher value to margin-left, for example "101%", and texts disappear.

Anyway I suggest you tu replace `margin-left` with *CSS translation*, according to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Paint_Flashing_Tool), for better performance. In this last case, due to particular behaviour of CSS transformation (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22970886/transformscale-vs-traditional-resizing/22971105#22971105)) you also don't need `overflow:hidden` on `Body` tag in order to avoid horizontal scrollbars.

```
 @keyframes slidein {
      0%   { transform: translate(101%); }
      100% {  transform: translate(0%); }
    }
```

Or, if you don't want to set a "strange" more than 100% value, you could combine my solution, with **@Herrington Darkholme**'s one.

Comment: The change of 100% to 101% didn't help for this problem (clearing initial text at the **left**), at least in my browser.
And transform: translate instead of margin-left is too cryptic for my taste (I didn't notice a difference in my browser either), but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Add margin-left to more than 100%

```
h1 {
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left: 105%;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0%   { margin-left: 105%; }
  100% { margin-left: 0%;   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution to the same problem:
We start with witdh:0px and overflow:hidden; (invisible) and end width:300px.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<head>
<style>

h1 {
  animation-name: slidein;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  color: red;
  font-size: 3.5em;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  0%   { margin-left: 100%; width:300px; }
  100% { margin-left: 0%;   width:300px;}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="animation-delay: 0s;">ONE</h1>
<h1 style="animation-delay: 1s;">TWO</h1>
<h1 style="animation-delay: 2s;">THREE</h1>

</body>
</html>
```